# Path Finder execute .app

Tags: osx-lion, hotkeys, pathfinder

As title says, is there a hotkey to execute a .app package from within Path Finder?
If you double-click/tap on a .app, Path Finder navigates into its package content. Is this maybe a setting that can be changed, if so, where?

I found out that (using OSX 10.7 Lion) it's possible to use spacebar while selecting a .app and then press 'open .app' at the top-right corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the *Show Package Contents* option on the *View* menu that leads to packages (including application bundles) being displayed and treated as folders:

[image]

---

If you want to keep this behavior, *and* are still running Finder, you can do the following:

Open *Path Finder » Set Menu Keys…* and navigate to the *Commands » Open With… » Running » Finder* menu item. Press `Cmd-Ctrl-1` or any other shortcut you want to use for this. Press it to run a selected application even with *Show Package Contents* checked by "opening" it via Finder.

[image]

You could also create a simple "Launcher" application e.g. in Automator that receives an path to an `.app` as argument and `open`s it. Then you don't need to keep Finder running. Setting up a keyboard shortcut in Path Finder works just like with *Finder*, except you don't choose the entry from the running applications list.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i found out i could also use 'space' to open preview, then click in the top-right corner on open (after the OSX 10.7 Lion update)